# Is there a way to use Pillows "Image.convert()" on an existing variable?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, grayscale

**Hello,**

maybe this question looks stupid, but I try to use Pillows `Image.convert()` to convert an image to grayscale. This image I have stored in a variable `img` because I already pre-processed it, but not with Pillow (type: numpy.ndarray). So I type:

```
img = Image.convert('LA')
```

But it does not seem to work, as it says:

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'convert'
```

If I type `img = Image.open("picture.jpg").convert('LA')` it works, but I want to use it on a variable that already exists. I also do not want to save the preprocessed image just to open and convert it with the previous command because this is even more inefficient (in terms of speed and CPU-power).
So: Is there a proper way to do this?

*Thanks for the help in advance!*

Comment: Have you tried ```img = img.convert('LA')```? you may or may not need to convert your numpy array to a PIL Image first using ```img = Image.fromarray(img)```

Comment: What is the shape of your Numpy array? And what do you plan to do with the image after you convert to greyscale?

Comment: @LampToast yes, I tried that as well, but it says "'img' has no attribute 'convert'". So this doesn't work either. If I use the conversion `img = Image.fromarray(img)`, which format is it stored in? Can I access the values of the individual pixels like in a numpy array, e.g. `img[1][1]`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The shape is (35, 64, 3). So a picture 64x35 with 3 color channels. After the conversion, I excepted a single greyscale value for each pixel, so it would be (35, 64, 1) or even just 2-dimensional. I need to access these values of each individual pixel e.g. through indexing (`img[0][0]` would be the first pixel)

Comment: @Totemi1324 if you use ```Image.fromarray(img)``` it will become a PIL Image. After the greyscale conversion you can simply convert back to a numpy array using ```img = np.asarray(img)``` or get the pixel values through ```px = img.load()```

Comment: @LampToast Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Totemi1324 I posted my comments as an answer in case anyone comes across this question in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you could perfectly well convert your Numpy array to a PIL Image and then convert that to greyscale and then convert back to a Numpy array like this:

```
PILImage = Image.fromarray(Numpyimg)
PILgrey  = PILImage.convert('L')
Numpygrey= np.array(PILgrey)
```

You might as well just do the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform yourself, i.e.

```
L = 0.299 * Red + 0.587 * Green + 0.114 * Blue
```

So, you would get:

```
Numpygrey = np.dot(Numpyimg[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]).astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saying `Image.convert()`
use your image variable:
img e.g
`img = img.convert('')`
and in this case:

`img = img.convert('LA')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
img = Image.fromarray(img)
```

to convert to a PIL Image type. From there, you should be able to use PIL's `convert()` function

```py
img = img.convert('LA')
```

then, to access the pixel values directly you can either convert back to a numpy array

```py
img_array = np.asarray(img)
```

or get pixel access to the PIL Image using

```py
pixels = img.load()
```