# Can I convert a color image into greyscale using Python and Pillow with custom weights instead of the built-in luma transform weights?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

Documentation for the PIL convert function says that:

> When translating a color image to greyscale (mode “L”), the library
>   uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform: L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 +
>   B * 114/1000

I would like to pass custom weights for the R, G and B in the calculation. How should I approach this?

Context: I'm trying to simulate color filters that are used in black and white photography to create mood & contrast. For example, the photographer can put a red filter, or an orange filter in front of the lens when taking a black and white photograph, resulting in different-looking photos. So my idea is to convert a color photo using weights that correspond to given filters. In the most simple case, the red filter would be L=R*1+G*0+B*0, an orange filter would be L=R*0.5+G*0.5+B*0.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531115/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use the syntax `L = R * 0.5 + G * 0.5 + B * 0`.
`R`, `G`, and `B` should be 2D arrays of type `float`.

- Since you are using PIL for reading the image, you need to convert the image to 3D RGB array (other packages read image as 3D array).
- Convert RGB elements from type `uint8` to type `float`.
- Do the math.
- Convert back to `uint8` and to PIL image.

Here is a sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

RGB = np.asarray(Image.open("rgb_input.png")) # Read RGB input image and convert to RGB array
RGB = RGB.astype('float') # Convert elements from uint8 to float
R, G, B = RGB[:, :, 0], RGB[:, :, 1], RGB[:, :, 2]  # Split RGB to R, G and B numpy arrays.
L =  R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000 # Convert to L (select your desired coefficients).
L = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(L)) #Format back to PIL image
L.show()
```

Remark: I don't have much Python experience - there are probably shorter solutions.