# Convert image numpy array into grayscale array directly without saving image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a NumPy array `img_array` of dimension `(h,w,3)` of one image, which is the result of some function. I want to convert this NumPy array directly into grayscale.

**Possible Solution:**
Save the `img_array` as image using `cv2.imwrite(path)`. Then read again with `cv2.imread(path, cv2.GRAYSCALE)`

However, I am looking for something like this :

```
def convert_array_to_grayscale_array(img_array):
        do something...
        return grayscare_version
```

I have already tried `cv2.imread(img_array, CV2.GRAYSCALE)`, but it is throwing error of `img_array` must be a file pathname.

I think saving a separate image will consume more space disk. Is there any better way to do that with or without using the OpenCV library function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Numpy Array to OpenCV Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587490/converting-numpy-array-to-opencv-array)

Comment: You can do it directly in Numpy - see last line here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531115/2836621

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thank you. I got it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scikit-image` has color conversion functions: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_rgb_to_gray.html

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

grayscale = rgb2gray(img_array)
```